# What is wrong with this Formula?

Tags: apex, community, formula

I'm trying to create a workflow to set a Customer Tier (Text) to "A", "B" or "C" depending on the number of employee.  The logic should be:

- C = 1-250
- B = 251-500
- A = 501+

The result is right for tier C but everything is incorrect.  Can someone spot my error within this logic?  The formula compiled without error.

```
If( NumberOfEmployees <=250, "C",if( 251 >= NumberOfEmployees &&  NumberOfEmployees  <= 500, "B", If( NumberOfEmployees < 500, "A", "None") ))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this nice and neat with just two `IF` functions since you don't have any gaps in your ranges:

```
IF(NumberOfEmployees <= 250, 'C',
 IF(NumberOfEmployees <= 500, 'B', 'A'))
```

Comment: I thought that as well, I just didn't know if the poster wanted 'A' to be there if NumberOfEmployees was null.

Comment: That would depend on the formula field option around nulls and blanks. In this case you'd want that set to zero I'd suspect.

Comment: Good point, my bad, its getting late here....lol

Answer (score 2):

251 >= NumberOfEmployee must be  **251 <= NumberOfEmployees**

AND

NumberOfEmployees < 500 must be **NumberOfEmployees > 500**

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax correct, you just have some of your operators a bit mixed up.  Just need to switch some of your Greater Than's (>), to Less Than's (<), and vice-versa.

This should work

```
IF(
     NumberOfEmployees <=250, 
     "C",
     IF(
          NumberOfEmployees >= 251 && NumberOfEmployees <= 500,
          "B",
          IF(
               NumberOfEmployees > 500,
               "A", 
               "None"
          )
     )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly altered formula which you can try

```
If( NumberOfEmployees <=250, "C",
    if( NumberOfEmployees >= 251 && NumberOfEmployees <= 500, "B", 
        If( NumberOfEmployees > 500, "A", "None") 
    )
)
```

also, if believe you can make this Customer Tier as a formula text field and directly use this formula in the field itself instead of a Workflow Rule + Field update (unless you want the field to be editable)

Comment: But make the formula shorter: `IF(ISNULL(NumberOfEmployees),"None", IF(NumberOfEmployees < 251, "C", If(NumberOfEmployees < 501, "B", "A")))` Remember that the compiled size is limited, so taking out the extra bit will reduce the compiled size a bit.

Comment: there's always a room for optimisations :-) and I prefer using ISBLANK instead of ISNULL